# Поиск данных в интервале времени. Oracle PL SQL date

Tags: oracle, время

Есть две таблицы:
Таблица А содержит в себе Имя, дату (с точностью до секунд) и номер. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица B содержит в себе практически те же данные, с поправкой на колличество строк и данных в таблице Date.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо для каждой строки из таблицы A применить следующий алгоритм действий:

Для каждой строки из таблицы А найти данные из таблицы B совпадающие по DATE и интервалом времени +- 15 минут. Например, мы ищем Для строки Alex с date 15.11.2022 18:01:48 данные из таблицы B с date от 15.11.2022 17:46:48 до 15.11.2022 18:16:48

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При условии, что поля **Date** имеют тип **TIMESTAMP**.

```
SELECT * FROM tableA a
JOIN tableB b ON a.name=b.name 
    AND a.date BETWEEN b.date - 1 / 24 / 4 
                   AND b.date + 1 / 24 / 4
```

Если формат поля varchar2 то потребуется преобразование значений в тип даты **to_date()**

> В Oracle с датой можно работать как с числом. 1 день это 1(единица). Для получения 15 минут, мы 1 делим на 24(часа), получаем 1 час, затем делим на 4, получаем 15 минут.

Comment: Работает, но можно ли как-то иным способом, нежели с помощью join? 
Иначе говоря, без JOIN

Comment: @tennant993 Вам же надо для каждой записи одной таблицы выбрать записи из другой? Можно конечно попробовать через вложенные запросы делать, но это плохой вариант.

Comment: Хорошо, понял. Благодарю за идею и за совет.